# How to count by one on a Windows form Application (C# Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I have a school project that wants me to make a windows Form Application in C#.
Each time I click the button It should add 1.

This was my first idea, but it says "Use of unsigned local variable.
If I set z to 0 at the start the problem is it resets it each time I click the button.  Any ideas?

```
int z;
z = z + 1;
txtBox.text = z.ToString();
```

I hope this makes sense. I am new to asking these types of questions online.
Thank you

Comment: Think about *where* you declare the variable. You need it somewhere where it will be around for the lifetime of the form, right?

Comment: Hint: you are defining z in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the 'z' variable inside the button click event scope, try declaring it just above the onClick method, also make sure to initialize it as 0

```
int z = 0;
private void Button_Click...
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't played with C# for a long time now

Answer (score 0):

This should work !

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int z;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        z = z +1;
        txtBox.Text = z.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked!!  After reading this and the other comments It all makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the code you provided is inside the "Button_click" method that was created by you double clicking on the button in the form designer.

The problem is that z needs to be declared outside that method, otherwise, as you noted is re-initialized to 0 every time you click the button.